# Fetching images from the Server and Display them as Banner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

- The server is sending a list of urls of images when the `application` loads.
- After parsing the url,The Application is Supposed to fetch that images from the server and display those images as **MARQUEE** on it's header as a **BANNER**.
- On Clicking on that `banner`...a `link` is to be open(Say for example link of any `WebSite`).

  Can Anybody tell me how to fetch this image from the url and `Save it temporarily` and `Display them` as Banner.

  Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview instead of Listview in your case display those in Banner

Comment: Please see the Edit..have added one More Point..:)

Comment: The marquee example is given here: https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code for loding img form url

```
ImageView v_thumburl = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.v_thumb_url);
        thumburl = temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex("thumburl"));
        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(thumburl);
        v_thumburl.setImageDrawable(drawable);

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

try this i hope it may help u

Answer (score 2):

- Use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for downloading images from server (Store them in external storage).
- After complete the download display those images in [**Gallery**](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) view as a
  Banner. (Put Gallery view in banner).
- As Android Gallery **doesn't support Marquee**, use **animation** for Gallery
  view ([Like Marquee](http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/06/creating-marqueelayout-with-android.html)).

Answer (score 1):

For Loading Image from The Server you can use [LasyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) which will fetch the image from server and store it into SD Card.

SlideShow will be better than Marquee, so if you want SlideShow see [this](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo)

And If you want marquee then what you can so is have and [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView)

Add a public Method in HorizontalListView Class as shown below

```
public void getScrollWidth() {
        return mMaxX;
    }

public void getCurrentScrollX() {
      return mNextX;
}
```

and For Marquee have a Thread and a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your class like this.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if((horizontalListView.getCurrentScrollX() + 50) < horizontalListView.getScrollWidth())
                                {
                                    horizontalListView.scrollTo(horizontalListView.getCurrentScrollX() + 50);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    horizontalListView.scrollTo(0);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            }).start();
```